# Automate screenshots of web sites requiring login

Tags: raspbian, script

I want to my raspberry go to a specified site, log in with specified data, and do a screenshot. Is it even possible?

Comment: You may also want to check out selenium and phantomJS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can easily write a script in python to automate the login

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11060439/filling-out-a-form-using-pyqt-and-qwebview

and save a screenshot of the site

https://webscraping.com/blog/Webpage-screenshots-with-webkit/